# Finding a string within a string using PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, regex, pdf, checkbox

I'm trying to find if a word, or string exists within a database field.  My scenario is:  User fills out a form and submits to MySQL database.  A checkbox element on the form saves to the database in a CSV format (Option 1, Option 2, Option 3).  I'm using Zend PDF to print a checkbox on a PDF form at certain positions depending on what is checked (IE on the PDF I have the options listed, if Option 2 is selected I want a checkbox next to it, if all 3 are selected then a checkbox needs to appear next to all 3).

I'm using Switch/Case logic to accomplish this:

```
switch ($row["MySQL_Field"]){
case "Option 1": $page->drawImage($checkmark,20,20,30,30);break;
case "Option 2": $page->drawImage($checkmark,40,40,50,50);break;
case "Option 3": $page->drawImage($checkmark,60,60,70,70);break;
}
```

Since the Database field can contain 'Option 1, Option 2, Option 3', I'm trying to figure out how to query so it looks like:

```
case "[0+ of any character]Option 1[0+ of any character]": do this;
```

What would be the best way to go about this?  Thanks!

Comment: you mean like using [`strstr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)??

Comment: not possible. `switch/case` is just a glorified `if/elseif/elseif`, where the `case` options are literally compared to the switch value with `==`. there's no expression/wildcard support. you'll have to use a regular `if` if you want to do "complex" matching.

Comment: I would suggest using regular `if`'s and then `strpos()` or RegEx `preg_match()`.

Comment: @MarcB to be fair, you could always `switch(true)` and have each case be an expression that evaluates to boolean. But that is generally frowned upon because it is less readable and isn't as clear as to what is happening.

Comment: I switch it to `if` but it doesn't seem to work:  
 `if ($row["MySQL_Field"] === strpos($row["MySQL_Field"],"Option 1"))
 {echo $row["MySQL_Field"];}`

Comment: `strpos(haystack, needle)` returns a number that is the number of characters into the haystack that the needle was found or it returns `false` if the needle was not found. You would likely want something more like: `strpos($row["Behavior"], "Aggressive") !== false`.

Comment: Perfect @JonathanKuhn Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With values like `"Option 1, Option 2, Option 3"`, you could just explode and then loop over the options, converting the option number to the position of your checkmark.

```
foreach (explode(',', $row['MySQL_Field']) as $value) {
    $x = substr($value, -1) * 20;
    $y = $x + 10;
    $page->drawImage($checkmark,$x,$x,$y,$y);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create new array for your switch like this:

```
$array_for_my_switch = array();
foreach ($row["MySQL_Field"] as $field) {
    if (strpos($field, 'Option 1') !== false) $array_for_my_switch[] = 'Option 1';
    if (strpos($field, 'Option 2') !== false) $array_for_my_switch[] = 'Option 2';
    if (strpos($field, 'Option 3') !== false) $array_for_my_switch[] = 'Option 3';
}

switch ($array_for_my_switch) {
    case "Option 1":
        $page->drawImage($checkmark, 20, 20, 30, 30);
        break;
    case "Option 2":
        $page->drawImage($checkmark, 40, 40, 50, 50);
        break;
    case "Option 3":
        $page->drawImage($checkmark, 60, 60, 70, 70);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks- this seems like a better long term solution vs `strpos` depending on the options in the checkbox field (IE if I had form options like 'active' and 'inactive' `strpos` would return a TRUE for both.

Comment: I would assume this wouldn't work and might throw errors. You can't switch on an array like that as the comparison in the case would be `Array() == "Option 1"`. It will never be true.